# MVC area and virtual folders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'd like the ability to add a sub "folder" to an MVC area. For instance, I have an area

```
~/areas/Support
```

And, in some classic ASP code, I need to refer to an include file

```
<!-- #include virtual="/Support/_inc/myinclude.asp"-->
```

Just for grins I tried including a virtual  folder `/support` that points to this virtual folder, but that, of course, overrides the MVC route and keeps the MVC stuff from executing.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that seems somewhat unconventional, but is working so far.

Under my test environment (IIS7.5 on Win7 Ultimate 64, ASP.NET MVC2), I edited the config file

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

and added virtual folders like so

```
<virtualDirectory path="/Support/_inc" physicalPath="C:\websites\virt\...\support\_inc" />
<virtualDirectory path="/support/man" physicalPath="c:\websites\http\...\support\man" />
<virtualDirectory path="/support/man/docs" physicalPath="c:\websites\virt\...\support\man\docs" />
<virtualDirectory path="/Support/docs" physicalPath="C:\websites\virt\...\support\docs" />
<virtualDirectory path="/Support/man/_inc" physicalPath="C:\websites\virt\...\support\man\_inc" />
```

since there is no virtual folder (or real folder, for that matter) at `/support`, MVC routes that to the /Areas/Support... items. Anything that matches the virtual folders in the application config, however, seem to be routed by IIS before ASP.NET takes over, so they are correctly handled by ASP.

Interesting.